# How to implement a language selector via JS that overrides global CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a simple CSS-based language switcher.

Consider a single static HTML page with content in, say, 3 languages:

```html
<h1 lang="en">Hello World</h1>
<h2 lang="de">Hallo Welt</h1>
<h2 lang="fr">Bonjour la Mond</h1>
...
<p lang="en">This is my english webpage...</p>
<p lang="de">Dies ist meine deutsche Webseite...</p>
<p lang="fr">Je ne parles pas francais</p>
```

When the page loads, we want to detect the user's language (`navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage`) and display only `:lang(en)` elements hiding all german or french sections.

```css
*[lang=en] {display:block}
*[lang=de] {display:none}
*[lang=fr] {display:none}
```

Now, if the user selects German, we want some JavaScript to switch the stylesheet out globally (not by element) so that we override the above CSS with:

```css
*[lang=en] {display:none}
*[lang=de] {display:block}
*[lang=fr] {display:none}
```

How can one achieve such a CSS override globally in JavaScript?

Notes:

- I don't want to select HTML elements and toggle their display - I want to overwrite the global CSS.
- How the language is selected is irelevant - it will be an `onclick` or `onchange` event which triggers the JS
- I don't mind having all `lang` elements display as block though it would be interesting how to toggle their display property between `none` and `<original>` without losing say `display:inline`.

Comment: I think you try to solve the problem from the wrong angle. Much better to have a translation lib such as i18n that covers basically all your needs. The solution you are after is kind of weird and inefficient, too - a.k.a "Why would you do that?".

Comment: It's just a proof of concept to have all languages in the same small HTML file and do a lang switch with a few lines of code without looping over DOM elements. Don't see what's "wrong" with approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only say this is a costly idea but basically doable

```js
const languages = ["en", "de", "fr", "ja"]

function changeLanguage(language) {
  if (!languages.includes(language)) language = languages[0]

  const style = document.querySelector("[data-type=css-language]") ?? document.createElement('style')
  style.textContent = `[lang="${language}"] { display: block }`
  style.setAttribute("data-type", "css-language")
  document.body.appendChild(style)
}



changeLanguage(navigator.language)
```

```css
[lang] { display: none }
```

```html
<h1 lang="en">Hello World</h1>
<h2 lang="de">Hallo Welt</h1>
<h2 lang="fr">Bonjour la Mond</h1>
<h2 lang="ja">こにちは</h1>
...
<p lang="en">This is my english webpage...</p>
<p lang="de">Dies ist meine deutsche Webseite...</p>
<p lang="fr">Je ne parles pas francais</p>
<p lang="ja">私わオタク</p>

<button onclick="changeLanguage('ja')">Switch to Japanese</button>
```

Comment: I see you are appending a style - so if we switch 20 times we add 20 elements. Is there no way to overwrite the CSS?

Comment: @Marc You can also remove the other entry first of course or replace the element itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild

Comment: i am looking for it if it is in the DOM i will override so there will never be more than 1 `<style>` in the DOM

Answer (score 2):

One way which I can think of achieving this is to create separate stylesheets for languages and then programmatically switch between them.

1. Create separate css files for each language.(You can put `display:block` to `*[lang=de] {display: block}` to german.css and others `none` and so on)

   ```css
    /* english.css */
    *[lang=en] {display:block}
    *[lang=de] {display:none}
    *[lang=fr] {display:none}
   ```
2. Add the link to that css file which you want to keep it as default. Also provide an `Id` to it.

   ```html
   <link id="languageStylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="english.css">
   ```
3. Create a function to switch the stylesheet based on selected language. *[`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)* is the key.

   ```js
   function switchLanguage(lang) {
   let stylesheetUrl;
   switch (lang) {
     case 'en':
       stylesheetUrl = 'english.css';
       break;
     case 'de':
       stylesheetUrl = 'german.css';
       break;
     case 'fr':
       stylesheetUrl = 'french.css';
       break;
     default:
       stylesheetUrl = 'english.css';
   }
    document.getElementById('languageStylesheet').setAttribute('href', stylesheetUrl);
   }
   ```

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/toggleCSSFile#index.html)***

Comment: It kinda works. But the problem is the stale state ... during the animation, the elements pop up and then they hide again so you see the French when you click on German etc. this is because when it loads no styles are present. Therefore, everything is visible.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way to do this is to set a class or a data attribute on a common ancestor element such as the `<html>` or `<body>` element.

Suppose we use a data attribute and call this `data-user-lang`.

Then your JS just sets this attribute's value to 'en', 'de' or 'fr' by whatever picker code you want.

All you need then is a single CSS rule:

```css
[data-user-lang=en] [lang]:not([lang=en]),
[data-user-lang=de] [lang]:not([lang=de]),
[data-user-lang=fr] [lang]:not([lang=fr]) { 
  display: none;
}
```

The display value of each element with a lang attribute which matches the selected language will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use CSS variables without using multiple stylesheets, or rewrite style. A fixed style sheet is created by JavaScript at pageload containing variables and rules.

To apply style we just need to set the CSS variables according to the language.

In the following demo the language is selected by a combobox just to show the functionality, which simply can be edited to set by navigator.language.

```js
function init() {
  const style = document.documentElement.style;
  const ss = document.getElementById("ss").sheet;
  const langs = document.querySelectorAll("#langs > option");
  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
    ss.insertRule(`[lang=${langs[i].value}] {display: var(--${langs[i].value});}`, i+1);
    // add CSS rule
    if (langs[i].selected) {
      var display = 'block';
    } else {
      var display = 'none';
    }
    style.setProperty('--' + langs[i].value, display);
    // add CSS variable
  }
  ss.removeRule(0);
  document.getElementById("langs").addEventListener('change', SetLanguage); 
}

function SetLanguage(value) {
  const selectedLanguage = document.querySelector("#langs").value;
  const langs = document.querySelectorAll("#langs > option");
  for (let lang of langs) {
    if (lang.value == selectedLanguage) {
      var display = 'block';
    } else {
      var display = 'none';
    }
    document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--' + lang.value, display);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```html
<style id="ss">
    [lang] {display: none;}
</style>

<label for="langs">Select Language:</label>
<select id="langs">
  <option value="en" selected="selected">English</option>
  <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
  <option value="fr">Français</option>
  <option value="fa">Persian</option>
</select>
<h1 lang="en">Hello World</h1>
<h1 lang="de">Hallo Welt</h1>
<h1 lang="fr">Bonjour la Mond</h1>
<h1 lang="fa">درود ای جهان</h1>
<p lang="en">This is my english webpage...</p>
<p lang="de">Dies ist meine deutsche Webseite...</p>
<p lang="fr">Je ne parles pas francais</p>
<p lang="fa">این سایت من به زبان پارسی است</p>
```

The style is initially empty, but has an id so we can access it and add rules at pageload event. In this demo the languages list is constructed from the combobox, which simply can be replaced by an array. The created style is equivalent to :

```
<style>
    :root {
        --en:block;
        --fr:none;
        --de:none;
        --fa:none;
    }

    [lang=en] {display: var(--en);}

    [lang=de] {display: var(--de);}

    [lang=fr] {display: var(--fr);}

    [lang=fa] {display: var(--fa);}
</style>
```

To display the selected language elements we just set the according CSS variable to display and set all other to none.

Answer (score 0):

I think that optimal tool for this task should be `:lang()` functional pseudo class exercised on entire document and individual elements, like:

```
html:lang(en) *:not(:lang(en)) /* , ... */ { display: none; }
```

Provided there are no foreign phrases marked in your content, in what case `*` should be replaced by a specific selector matching "containers" to be toggled.

This feels quite idiomatic / semantic, since if we hide all "other" language blocks, the document should receive `lang="<that language's code>"`, what can be exploited further.

Simple demo with `lang` attribute on global parent (here `body`) is switched with buttons, plus some attempt for "i18n":

```css
body:lang(en) *:not(:lang(en)) ,
body:lang(de) *:not(:lang(de)) ,
body:lang(fr) *:not(:lang(fr)) {
 opacity: .3;
 /* ↑ for demonstrative purposes, instead of display: none.*/
}


/* --- whimsicality (and fixes) --- */
button > span::after {
 content: ' ';
 word-spacing: 1ch;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 calc(50% - .1pt), currentcolor 0 calc(50% + .1pt), transparent 0);
}
p {
 margin: 0;
}

[value="en"]:lang(en) ,
[value="de"]:lang(de) ,
[value="fr"]:lang(fr) {
 &::before { content: ' '; }
}
/*
This should fix borked flags outside Firefox, but let's not spam xem's github.
(Plus, cannot verify ATM.)
@font-face {
 font-family: twemojimoz;
  src: local(Twemoji Mozilla),
  url(https://xem.github.io/unicode13/Twemoji.ttf);
}
.flags {
 font-family: sans-serif, serif, twemojimoz;
}
*/
```

```html
<body lang="">

<p lang="en">Hello!
<p lang="de">Hallo!
<p lang="fr">Bonjour!
 
<ul>
<li><button onclick="body.lang=value" value=""><span lang=""></span> <span lang="en">All languages</span> <span lang="de">Alle Sprachen</span> <span lang="fr">Toutes les langues</span></button>
<li><button onclick="body.lang=value" value="en"><span lang="">☕ <span class="flags">  </span></span> <span lang="en">English</span> <span lang="de">Englisch</span> <span lang="fr">Anglais</span></button>
<li><button onclick="body.lang=value" value="de"><span lang=""> <span class="flags">  </span></span> <span lang="en">German</span> <span lang="de">Deutsch</span> <span lang="fr">Allemand</span></button>
<li><button onclick="body.lang=value" value="fr"><span lang=""> <span class="flags">  </span></span> <span lang="en">French</span> <span lang="de">Französisch</span> <span lang="fr">Français</span></button>
</ul>
```